# Jquery Color Picker in Ember

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js, color-picker

I have a button in my Ember on its click I want to call an action where the Jquery colorpicker will op up. The problem is this the first time click on the button nothing happens but the second time it starts working.

In my message.hbs file I want to get this. How can I get colorpicker to appear on click on my button?

In my color_picker.js I am doing like this.

```
Cards.ColorPicker = Em.View.extend({
classNames: ['cmp-colpick'],
pluglin: null,
templateName: 'color-picker',
didInsertElement: function() {
    this.plugin = this.$().colpick({
        layout: 'hex',
        submit: 0,
        color: '#000000',
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb, el, bySetColor) {
            $('#postcard_message').css("color", '#' + hex);
            $('.color-preview').css("background-color", '#' + hex);
            $('#font-color').colpickHide();
        }
    });
},
willDestroyElement: function() {
    //Destroy plugin
}
```

});
I want the color picker to start working on one click. I don't want to click the button twice. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to debug it and check if the function is called on the first time? I personally need more information to try and help.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I put an alert in the function. First time it did that alert but nothing with the color picker. Next time it starts the color picker but not any alert.

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/behuwipa/2/edit here is a working example. You see you have to click twice on the button to make it work.

Comment: I also have an custom ember view with an action that does nothing when clicked the first time, then works perfectly thereafter. very mysterious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jquery plugins, wrapping them in views is a goof practice.
Here is the [demo link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/behuwipa/4/edit).

Here is the relevant code

```
App.ColorPicker = Em.View.extend({
    classNames: ['cmp-colpick'],
    pluglin: null,
    templateName: 'color-picker',
    didInsertElement: function() {
      this.plugin = this.$().colpick({
        layout: 'hex',
        submit: 0,
        color: '#000000',
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb, el, bySetColor) {
          console.log('sdf');
          $('body').css("background", '#' + hex);
        }
      });
    },
    willDestroyElement: function() {
      //Destroy plugin
    }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index"> 
  {{view App.ColorPicker}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="color-picker">
  <button>Choose Color</button>
</script>
```

Comment: I already added a working demo in my answer. I cant find anything wrong with ur current code. Maybe a failing bin with updated code will help.